# How could I force PHP to use bash version 4.0 or newer?

Tags: php, bash

I am running bash scripts from PHP page. I am using XAMPP server on localhost.
using these commands:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('../scripts/simple.sh');
$output = null;
$return_var = null;
$contents = escapeshellarg($contents);
exec("bash -c $contents 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
```

I added this command to my bash script to see which version is running:

```
bash --version
```

When I run the bash script from the terminal using `./simple.sh` it uses bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)
```

However, when I run it from PHP page it uses :

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
```

How could I force PHP to use bash version 4.0 or newer?

note: I also tried `exec("/usr/local/bin/bash -c $contents 2>&1", $output, $return_var);` and got the same output as above

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("/bin/bash_your_version -c $contents 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
```

Comment: I tried that  `exec("/usr/local/bin/bash -c $contents 2>&1", $output, $return_var);` it still use the version 3 and `which bash` command from Php return `/bin/bash`

Comment: I need v4 or newer because I have associative arrays inside my scripts which is not supported in v3

Comment: You should have another alias in your bin folder. Something like /bin/bash4.0

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: I added alias and test the new alias in the terminal and it works, however when  I use that new alias in the exec command, php does not recognized it and show this error `sh: bash5.0: command not found `

Comment: It really sounds like you're running your bash commands on one system, and your PHP on an entirely different system.